# Constructing Proxy type given the input

Tags: haskell, data-kinds

Given the code below which looks up type-specific information in `Data.HashMap` for a type, is it possible to define a new function `getMapVal2` as documented in the comments, to build the `TypeKey` argument given the type?

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Data.Proxy (Proxy(Proxy))
import GHC.TypeLits (KnownSymbol, Symbol, symbolVal)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as Map (HashMap, empty, insert, lookup)
import Data.Dynamic
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Maybe (fromJust, isNothing, maybe)

type family TypeKey (a :: *) :: Symbol where
    TypeKey Int = "int"
    TypeKey T = "trec"

data T = T { aInt :: Int} deriving (Show, Generic, Typeable)

extract ::(s ~ TypeKey a, Typeable a, KnownSymbol s) => Maybe Dynamic -> Maybe a
extract dyn = if (isNothing dyn) then Nothing else fromDynamic . fromJust $ dyn   

getMapVal :: (s ~ TypeKey a, Typeable a, KnownSymbol s) => Map.HashMap String Dynamic -> String -> Maybe a
getMapVal m k = extract $ Map.lookup k m 

{-- How do we get the TypeKey lookup for type a?
getMapVal2 :: (s ~ TypeKey a, Typeable a, KnownSymbol s) => Map.HashMap String Dynamic -> a -> Maybe a
getMapVal2 m ty = extract $ Map.lookup (symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy (TypeKey ???))) m
--}

main = do
  let map = Map.insert (symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy (TypeKey T))) (toDyn $ T {aInt=5}) Map.empty -- we insert some value in hashmap for type T - it is of same type
      val = getMapVal map (symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy (TypeKey T))) :: Maybe T -- now let us retrieve the value in map for Type T. We pass the SymbolVal ourselves
    --val =  getMapVal2 map (T {aInt = 2}) -- now we want to lookup map value given something of a type T. Need getMapVal2 to build symbolval given the input type
  print $ maybe "" show val -- prints value stored in Hashmap for type T which is: T {aInt=5}
```

This is just a toy code to test passing type specific configuration at run-time via `Data.HashMap` to a polymorphic function that acts on types of a typeclass.

Comment: Incidentally, what are you trying to achieve here? I notice a few code smells: dynamic typing, "stringly typed" type-level computation, [non-covering closed type families](https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/what-are-type-families/). I wonder if your life might be easier if you were to reorganise your code around singleton values instead.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, yep, I don't like this approach, but here is what I am trying to solve: given a set of data constructors of different types, define a polymorphic function over that set that calls type-specific builder (some kind of XML template - data of a type `a` gets translated to an XML request of type `a`). For that, I need to load builders at run-time configuration, and pass to the function so that it can, given data of type `a`, retrieve the builder of type `a`, and then call it. That function is couple of functions away from `main`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, I also considered [reification approach](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/thoughtpolice/using-reflection) (basically, define a typeclass with the builder and the builder function, and pass the builder at runtime. However, the code I came up with in my head doesn't look clean either. Perhaps reification is a better approach, and I should create another question at SO.

Comment: I'm concerned that you may be bringing imperative(/OO(/Java))-style thinking to a functional environment. To me this sounds like a textbook use-case for classes: `class ToXml a where { toXml :: a -> Xml }`. No need for complicated code like this or `reflection`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, however, `toXML` itself is run-time load from a file, not compile-time. In case it puts you at ease, I haven't programmed in imperative languages in long time :) It is just that this problem itself seems to be imperative - in main, we do this (this is a `heist` compiled builder actually): `aFn :: StateT AnAPI IO Builder <- genBuilder "curdir" "atemplate"`. It probably isn't possible to instantiate a compile-time class with run-time `aFn` member.

Comment: This is an interesting situation. I suspect Haskell's dependently-typed facilities can be used to give a neat, typed way of doing what you need. However, the nature of the solution depends on a number of variables, such as whether the set of serialisable types is known and finite. I think this warrants a separate question with more details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108057/discussion-between-sal-and-benjamin-hodgson).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables). This allows you to refer to `forall`-bound type variables in the body of the definition in which they are bound.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

getMapVal2 :: forall a s. (s ~ TypeKey a, Typeable a, KnownSymbol s) => Map.HashMap String Dynamic -> a -> Maybe a
getMapVal2 m ty = extract $ Map.lookup (symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy (TypeKey a))) m
```