# Passing runtime information for polymorphic function

Tags: haskell, typeclass

This is follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375610/constructing-proxy-type-given-the-input) about type-indexed map. Following the discussion in the comments, I am posting the actual problem here to see if there is a neat way to solve this using dependent-type programming.

The problem is that given run-time information that we need for a typeclass function - we have different types of messages coming over the wire, and we use that function to do message specific processing using the run-time configuration - how do we pass run-time information (one run-time configuration for each type instance) to that function?

Toy code below with comments - we use typeclass function `f` within `g` which gets runtime information and applies it to `f`  - btw, the set of message types `a` is fixed - so, we can use closed typefamilies if need be:

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let runtimeinfo = Mesg { aString = "someheader"}
      builder = (\x -> Mesg { aString = (aString runtimeinfo) ++ (aString x)})  
  -- should call function "app" on this line which will call function "g"
  return () 

data Mesg = Mesg {aString :: String} deriving Show

class Process a where
  f :: a -> a -- FYI, in actual app, output type is (StateT a IO Builder)
  -- We can't define builder below at compile-time because it is created at run-time in main above
--builder :: a -> a 

instance Process Mesg where
  f inp = Mesg { aString = (reverse (aString inp))} -- contrived example - a placeholder for some processing on message

-- g is not directly reachable from main - main calls a function "app" which 
-- calls g (after receiving "inp" of type "a" over the wire) - so, to pass 
-- builder, we have to pass it along. builder is from runtime configuration - 
-- in this example, it is created in main. If it were part of typeclass Process,
-- we won't need to pass it along
g :: Process a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
g builder inp = builder $ f inp -- we call processing function f here with runtime builder

-- Alternative approach pseudo code - map here is created in main, and passed to g via app
{--
 g :: (Process a, Typeable a) => Map String Dynamic -> a -> Maybe a
 g map inp = (retrieve corresponding builder from map using type-indexed string), apply here with f
--}
```

My solution so far is type-indexed map in `g` which looks up `builder` for the type `a`.

Comment: I think the type of `g` is strange.. why does it return a string? Why not start with a function `:: (Process a, Typeable a) => Map String Dynamic -> Maybe (a -> a)` which computes the string from the `TypeRep` and returns the desired function (wrapped in Maybe of course).

Comment: @user2407038, my bad about commented version of `g`. Should return `Maybe a`. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This question really isn't self-contained, but it sounds like you might be able to use the facilities in the [`reflection`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) package. In particular, it lets you use runtime information in typeclass instances. For example, you could write something like this (untested).

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables,
      UndecidableInstances, .... #-}
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Reflection

data Configuration a = Configuration
  { the_builder :: a -> a
  , someOtherThing :: Int
  , whatever :: Char }

class Buildable a where
  builder :: a -> a

newtype Yeah s a = Yeah a

instance Reifies s (Configuration a) =>
            Buildable (Yeah s a) where
  builder (Yeah x) = Yeah $ the_builder (reflect (Proxy :: Proxy s)) x
```

Then you can write

```
reify config $ \(_ :: Proxy s) -> expr
```

and within `expr`, the type `Yeah s a` will be an instance of the `Buildable` class.

Comment: If we call reify within main, is the created instance visible outside the main body, i.e., it has global scope like compile-time typeclass instance? This is one thing about reflection dynamic typeclass instances that hasn't been clear to me.

Comment: @Sal The instance `Buildable (Yeah s a)` is a normal instance; it has a global scope just like any instance. You just can't satisfy it without the `Reifies s (Configuration a)` context, which means that the instance is only _usable_ inside a call to `reify`. In practice, all this means is that you can't write a second instance `Buildable (Yeah s a)` which overlaps this one, as GHC never uses instance contexts to choose between two instances.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to change the declaration of `builder`, why not do it the old-fashioned way and just plumb in the config using a monad?

```
data Config = Config {
    theHeader :: String,
    somethingElse :: Int,
    andAnotherThing :: Bool
}

class Buildable a where
    build :: MonadReader Config m => String -> m a


data Msg = Msg { msg :: String } deriving (Show)

instance Buildable Msg where
    build body = do
        config <- ask
        return $ Msg { msg = theHeader config ++ body }


-- imagine we're getting this from a file in the IO monad
readConfigFile = return $ Config {
    theHeader = "foo",
    somethingElse = 4,
    andAnotherThing = False
}
-- imagine we're reading this from the wire
getFromSocket = return "bar"

main = do
    config <- readConfigFile
    body <- getFromSocket
    msg <- runReaderT (build body) config
    print msg
```

@dfeuer's `reflection` answer becomes useful if you don't own the class and can't add the monadic context to `build`'s type.

Comment: yep, I don't own the `build`

Comment: You don't own the `Process` class you had in your question?

Comment: Yep, I do own the `Process` class.

Comment: So what's the problem? Put `build` in your `Process` class, as you originally intended, with a type which gives it access to the run-time config. Keep it simple. You don't need `reflection` or `DataKinds` or `Dynamic`.

Comment: Yep, figuring out how to refactor process class. No need for Reflection then.

Comment: don't we have to pass `config` argument for readerT to the function which will call `build` on the message? If so, then, we have n config for n type instances of message, no?

Comment: I don't understand your question. My proposed design is not complicated: you read the config file(s) into a single in-memory data structure; each implementation of `build` receives the config data through the reader monad and uses it to decide how to build whatever it needs to build. One config, `n` instances.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108096/discussion-between-sal-and-benjamin-hodgson).